# Why I cannot use Django Signals to reload HTML page

Tags: django, django-templates, signals

I want to reload or refresh a HTML page (block content) when a specific table from the database is saved. My first idea was to use Django Signals (post-save() method). This trigger would have triggered a view or rendered a html template. But I read that it is not possible and/or it's not best practice.

Why it is not possible to use a Django Signal for this purpose and what is the best practice? Do you know another methodology than avoid AJAX request?

Many thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Are you aware of Django-Channels? https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: No I am not aware of Django-Channels. I will have a look. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is not possible is because a Django Signal is just a hook that runs a function when a signal is triggered. This does not change the fact that your webpage is still using HTTP, which is stateless. This means that once your page is rendered by the server and then sent to your client (Chrome, IE, etc), the connection is essentially closed.

In order to keep an open channel, you can use something called WebSockets to keep the connection alive, just as @schillingt mentioned. This will allow you to have real-time updates on the user's page.

> Django Channels docs: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you for your explanation